# Backpropagation neuron networks

Tags: neural-network, genetic-algorithm, backpropagation, supervised-learning, unsupervised-learning

Hi I playing with neural nets right now. I made kind of reimplementation of this tutorial: 
http://www.ai-junkie.com/ann/evolved/nnt5.html, but with fishes and food and also different programing language. But the point is same.

I have bunch of fishes (20) and bunch of foos (40).
Each fish has brain(neural network (I will use ANN since now)). At the moment neural network don't use backprop and is trained by genetic alghoritm. It works fine. I want to implement learning by using backpropagation and than compare this two approaches. Problem is only with backpropagation alghoritm. I read some articles about it but i kind of didn't get the point how it actually could be used on this example. I probably just don't understand it enought. 
**I'll explain the problem:**

Now i have neural network with 4 inputs. LookAt vector lookAt(x,y), vector to closest food  closestFood(x,y) => the values of this vectors are inputs to the ANN. Output of the nn is speed of left an right flipper of the fish => ANN has 2 outputs leftFliperSpeed, rightFlipperSpeed. 
So to sum up. I have ann like this: 
inputs: 4 (lookAt.X,lookAt.Y, closestFood.X,closestFood.Y)
layers: 3 (input, output, and one hidden with 6 neurons) 
outputs: 2 (leftFlipperSpeed, rightFlipperSpeed)

**I use it like this:**

1. By genetic alghoritm I get the first population of fishes (read I will get the weights for inputs of ANN).
2. Run for some number of iterations the simulation and let the fishes eat the fishes find and eat the food. I fish found the food, her fitness function is increased and food is repositioned somewhere else. I have constant number of fishes and food all the time.
3. After for example 2000 iterations I run again the genetic alghoritm and get from actual population new population - fishes with higher fitness has higher chance to survive or be dad or mom of new fishes. I get new weights for the Neural newtork. And continue from point 2. 

The learning process is easy and clear here. And its learning without supervisor.

Now the backpropagation. From articles I read the backpropagation is supervised learning. The problem is with training set. With genetics alghs i didn't need it here yes. 
What could I do to implement backpropagation. 
 Any tips how could I get the the new weights from it and how to replace the supervisor? I think backpropagation can't be done without supervisor. It can be somehow used the data which I get from learning by genetic alghoritm but its will be dependent on number of inputs, size of pool with food where will be fishes, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Backpropagation is just a method of computing gradients, nothing else. It is not really the supervised learning technique, it is only about being able to efficiently compute gradients of some prefefined loss function (which often, in examples online will be supervised loss).

For the problem described the most reasonable technique is actually **reinforcement learning**. There, you will be able to backprop through your networks, and learn feeding policies in a well structured manner (as opposed to genetic algorithm which will fail with any more complex problem). You might want to take a look at objects like Deep Q-learning (which efficiently is just a simple RL technique where your policy is controled by a neural net, and this is exactly what you try to achieve - you have a neural net based policy, which chooses actions; although in your case it is a continuous output space thus you might need to discretize it for this particular use case).